# Shortcut key to add quotes in pandas list

Tags: python, pandas

I have copied some of the names from a website and kept it in a list:

```
lst = [Steve
       Joseph
       John
       Aaron
       Lisa
       ]
```

But this is not a correct list format of strings so I want to make it like this:

```
lst = ['Steve',
       'Joseph',
       'John',
       'Aaron',
       'Lisa'
       ]
```

Is there any shortcut key to achieve it or I have to do it manually ?? There are totally 167 names so doing it manually is a time taking process that's why I was asking

Comment: You input is not valid python, unless `Steve` is a variable, you have to better explain what you want. Maybe `out = [f"'{x}'" for x in lst]`. If `lst` is a Series: `df['lst'] = "'" + df['lst'] + "'"`

Comment: Copy the names to a text file instead and programmatically read that text file…? That's just two lines of code, but you don't need to alter the data at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in an IDE you can make use of *multiple cursors*.

For example, in VS Code you can do the following:

1. Place your cursor before the word Steve
2. Whilst holding Ctrl + Alt (or Cmd + Option on Mac) press ↓
3. You will now have a second cursor, which is before the word Joseph
4. Repeat step 2 until you have a cursor on each desired line
5. Press ' to create quotes around each word on each line with a cursor
6. Press End to move each cursor to the end of the line
7. Press , to add a comma to end of each line

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use [pyperclip](/questions/tagged/pyperclip) :

```
#pip install pyperclip
import pyperclip

lst = pyperclip.paste().split("\n") # <- change \n to any separator
#['Steve', 'Joseph', 'John', 'Aaron', 'Lisa']
```

And since you have a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, you can also use [`read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html) :

```
lst = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)[0].tolist()
#['Steve', 'Joseph', 'John', 'Aaron', 'Lisa']
```

After that, if needed, you can use [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) and set `width=1` :

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(lst, width=1)
​
['Steve',
 'Joseph',
 'John',
 'Aaron',
 'Lisa']
```

NB: If you're using a code editor like *Visual Studio Code*, *Sublime Text*, .. you can simply install the `autopep8` extension to reformat the `lst` assignement.

*Clipboard used :*

```
#pyperclip.paste()
#'Steve\nJoseph\nJohn\nAaron\nLisa'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any text editor will have find-replace with regular expressions.

So this is a general guide for use in any text editor, including VSCode, Notepad++, etc.

Select the range of text where you want to add single quotes.

Check a box that says "find/replace in selection" or something to that effect. (*you want to only do this on the selected text*).

Replace `(\w+)` with `'$1'`.

Explanation:

1. `(\w+)` finds and "captures" all instances of one or more consecutive "word characters", which includes numbers, letters, and underscore.

   - If you prefer to match only letters, `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `\w` will work fine.
2. In the replacement, `'$1'` returns the "captured" words wrapped in single quotes.

   - In some regex implementations, like python `re`, you will have to use `\1` instead of `$1`.

Some of my favorite regex references include [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/) and the [python `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).